# How do I change the str of my diff time from atomic to num

Tags: r

So this is a simple example, but when I do

```
>t1 <- as.POSIXlt("2015-02-02 20:13:03 00:00:00")
>t2 <- as.POSIXlt("2015-02-02 20:18:02 00:00:00")
>str(difftime(t1, t2))
```

The output I get is

```
>Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:1] -4.98
  >..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"
```

however I want to get the result to look like

```
>Class 'difftime'  num [1:1] -4.98
  >..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"
```

How am I supposed to change it to num? as.Numeric doesn't work as it changes the whole thing into a numeric. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get `'difftime' num -4.98333333333333
 - attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"`.

Comment: Besides, your output is not right, atomic objects have no attributes.

Comment: Huh that is very weird I tried putting it in again and I still get atomic. When I put in t1-t2 I get                                                                                    
>Time difference of -4.983333 mins

Comment: My output of `t1 - t2` is the same as yours. What version of R are you using?

Comment: The version I am using is 1.0.153

Comment: I'm very surprised, R version 1.0.1 is dated April 2000. Time to update! Download from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/), the official repository.

Comment: @RuiBarradas even for R 3.4.3 I get `Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:1] -4.98
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"`

Comment: @hellspond3: Please learn that R and Rstudio are two things: The latter needs the former. Almost surely `1.0.153` is your Rstudio version and that is absolutely irrelevant.  It's embarrassing (for Rstudio) and misleading if you don't easily get the R version.   In R itself, use `getRversion()`, and then please report here.